# comparing createddate column with getdate() function

Tags: sql-server

I have a datetime column - createddatetime with this value 2015-02-10 23:54:02.000

All I have to do is to compare ONLY THE DATE with getdate() function (Time can be ignored)

How should the query be written.

the pseudo query is:

```
 select * from table where createddatetime(only date) = getdate(only date)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

USE CAST or CONVERT function:

```
select * from table where cast(createddatetime as date) = cast(getdate() as date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Lots of ways.   My favorite is with DATEDIFF()

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE DATEDIFF(day,createddatetime,getdate()) = 0
```

Comment: All he wants is to pick the date part from datetime part. WHAT way DATEDIFF() will be used here.

Comment: If createddatetime and getdate both are on the same day, regardless of time, then the DateDiff(day) will be 0.

Comment: The only issue there is that it renders the where predicate nonSARGable. If casting as a DATE the query engine can still utilize indexes if they are present.

Comment: I was under the impression that any function, including CAST and CONVERT, will prevent the query engine from using indexes.   Is this documented?